# It's so confused with the Hibernate Validator @Email constraint

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I want to validate step by step, that is to say, if one constraint is falied, the next one will not be check, I defined the constraints in model like this:

```
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 4, max = 40)
private String password;

@NotEmpty
@Email
private String email;
```

for the two properties, the validate result is different, if the password is empty, the error print is :

```
Password cant be empty
Password must be between 4 and 40 characters
```

but for email, the error print is :

```
Email cant be empty
```

for the email, the result is what I want, but I didn't know what's the difference between the @Email constraint and others, if there have some especial handler for the @Email constraint in the hibernate internal code?

I want validate step by step, but I didn't find out a perfect approach, the @GroupSequence also isn't a good scheme, I found the @Email have the feature, but I didn't know why @Email perform so especial.

Comment: Actually both validations are invoked for email too. When you look at the `EmailValidator` source code, it considers empty or null String as valid ...

Comment: oh,Bohuslav, I see, I know the reason about the @Email constraint, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty string will not fail the `@Email` check. So, the `email` property will only have one error for the `@NotEmpty`.

You can achieve something similar to what you want, but not exactly, using one of the following methods:

1- [Enable `failfast`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-fail-fast). This will stop the validation at the first invalid property (other properties will not be validated).

```
Validator validator = Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
        .configure()
        .failFast( true )
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```

2- Create a composite constraint with `@ReportAsSingleViolation` annotation. This will stop the validation of a property at the first error, but you can't have different messages for each constraint error.

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
@Documented
@Size(min = 4, max = 10)
@NotEmpty
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String message() default "single.error.message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

3- [Use `@GroupSequence`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-defining-group-sequences) to control the order of validation, and to stop validating the following groups when the current group fails.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, only option 3 from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27212967/115835) will do what you want. You need to realize that annotations in Java are not order based and there is no guarantee that if you place annotation in a certain order, that they will be retrieved in that order when using reflection. The only reliable way of enforcing a validation order using Bean Validation is via the `GroupSequence` feature. There are discussions ([BVAL-248](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-248)) to add some sort of ordering support for an upcoming version of Bean Validation, but this is still undecided and of course not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was successfully answered a long time ago, but thought I'd add that the easiest thing to do is not mix `@Size` and `@NotEmpty` on the same String field.

If Size says "cannot be less than `min`", and NotEmpty is saying "cannot be less than one", they have overlapping responsibilities and you will see two errors.

It's fine for the `@Email` field, because as stated, `null` and `""` are considered valid email addresses and as such, there is no overlap here.